How to delete both original and duplicate values in different lines a notepad++
How to delete both original and duplicate values in different lines a notepad++
Example
2
3
2
2
2
2

Desired
3


You can't do such job in Notepad++ natively if the lines are not sorted. You have to use a PythonScript (for example) or write a script in your favorite scripting language.

If you sort and then remove any two rows matching, any cases of odd numbers of the same number would result in one left over. I don't know if there's a way to match 2 or more rows with the same value in Notepad++. I would guess, therefore, that Toto is correct and you'll need to use something other than Notepad++, a scripting tool (Python, PowerShell, etc) or a program that supports macros. Note that SuperUser is not a script-writing service, so you'll want to begin looking into these tools and work on writing such a script.

Edit: the question was modified after I posted the answer.


Make a copy of your document just in case
Search -> Replace or Ctrl+H /Cmd+H
In "Find What" "2 3 2 2 2 2" In "Replace With" enter "3"
Choose "Replace All" to replace all instances immediately
or use "Find Next"/"Replace" to move step by step to test if
everything's working how you want


I think you didn't undertand the question. What about lines like: 1 2 1 2 1 2 3 1 2

I understood the question but what I answered was edited out hours before your comment

No, you didn't. Your answer only works for a specific number of lines. It doesn't work for a line like: 1 2 1 2 1 2 3 1 2

Before being edited the question essentially was asking how to replace a string with another string. The "Search and Replace All" I suggested does just that on every instance, not just specific number of lines.
